# ListPlot with plotmarkers determined by point

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

I am trying to build on a simple example here:

```
td = Prime[Range[25]]
dsk = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}]
ListPlot[td, PlotMarkers -> {dsk, 0.7}]
```

How can I make Plotmarkers be a function of points being plotted?

Comment: Can you give an example of the functionality you're looking for?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The description in the question suggests that you may *really* want to use [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BubbleChart.html) instead of `ListPlot`.

You want the plot markers to be a function of the points, and that's exactly what `BubbleChart` is originally meant to do. It's a relatively new function, but I'll describe how to use it for a simple example based on your prime number table.

In a `BubbleChart`, each data point has three entries: the `x` and `y` coordinates of the point at which the marker is supposed to appear, and a "radius" variable `r` that determines the size and color of the marker.

The *shape* of the marker is set by the option `"ChartElements"`, and I'll leave that in its default state (which is a disk as you asked for anyway).

This means that in addition to your table

```
td = Prime[Range[25]];
```

we need a data table with three entries for each of the `25` points. For the radius of the disks, I'll pretend that I want to make the marker smallest when the prime number is closest to `50`:

```
data = MapIndexed[Join[#2, {#1, Abs[#1 - 50]/50}] &, td] // N
```

Now let's plot this:

```
BubbleChart[data]
```

[image: bubble1]

As an additional way of visualizing the data, we can use the third entry in the point's data to change the color of the disks:

```
BubbleChart[data, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3/10] &)]
```

[image: bubble colors]

The documentation shows how you can use arbitrary shapes other than disks, too. It also shows that you can combine several data sets in a single plot if desired.

**Edit**

One additional issue appears in the answer by kguler and motivated Sjoerd's answer (both of which are fine so I upvoted them of course): it's the question of how to plot these data dependent plot markers and then *also* draw a line through the data.

The answer is actually very simple - and that also means kguler's answer can be used this way: just combine the `BubbleChart` with a separate `ListLinePlot` of the same data using `Show`:

```
Show[%, ListLinePlot[td]]
```

[image: show line]

That should cover all the possible issues.

**Edit 2: using `ErrorListPlot`**

There is another alternative to get individually styled plot markers. This may be useful when you don't need or want the dynamic interactivity that's built into `BubbleChart` by default. Of course in general it's nice to have tooltips, mouse-over highlighting etc. But it does require enabling dynamic interactivity in the notebook, whereas `ListPlot` doe *not* require that.

An approach that's closer to `ListPlot` in its *lack* of interactivity would be to use `ErrorListPlot`, which requires loading the `ErrorBarPlots` package. The idea is that an `ErrorBar` is a kind of plot marker, and it obviously is also designed to vary from point to point. Furthermore, it's possible to define custom error bars (including disks) by specifying the option `ErrorBarFunction`.

Continuing with the above prime number example, the `data` list can be simplified by leaving out the first index corresponding to the `x` coordinate.

```
data1 = data[[All, 2 ;; 3]]

(*
==> {{2., 0.96}, {3., 0.94}, {5., 0.9}, {7., 0.86}, {11., 
  0.78}, {13., 0.74}, {17., 0.66}, {19., 0.62}, {23., 0.54}, {29., 
  0.42}, {31., 0.38}, {37., 0.26}, {41., 0.18}, {43., 0.14}, {47., 
  0.06}, {53., 0.06}, {59., 0.18}, {61., 0.22}, {67., 0.34}, {71., 
  0.42}, {73., 0.46}, {79., 0.58}, {83., 0.66}, {89., 0.78}, {97., 
  0.94}}
*)
```

Then I load the package and define a function to create a more or less arbitrary "plot marker"  whose size and color are determined by the second number in each tuple of `data1`, which is passed to the function as a variable `err`. I also let the rotation angle vary as a function of the `x` coordinate which is automatically generated here). This is done in `errorfunction` - and that's where you can do all your own customization (for variety I chose squares instead of disks here):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

errorfunction[{x_, y_}, err_] := Inset[
  Graphics[{
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Last[Flatten[List @@ err]]],
    Rotate[Rectangle[{-.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}], Pi x/12]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  (* Here comes the positioning and the scaling: *)
  {x, y},
  Center,
  ImageScaled[Last[err]/5]
  ]

ErrorListPlot[data1, ErrorBarFunction -> errorfunction, PlotMarkers -> ""]
```

[image: error plot]

The actual `PlotMarkers` should be suppressed so that only the error bars are left to play the role of markers. That's why I added `PlotMarkers -> ""`.

Comment: You have certainly covered more than I had imagined doing!

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps something like:

```
  ListPlot[MapIndexed[{Join[#2, #1]} &, Split@td], 
  PlotMarkers -> (Style[Framed[#], "Subsubsection", 
  Hue[RandomReal[]]] & /@ td), Frame -> True, 
  DataRange -> {10, 30}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The issue of `Joined` plots can be solved in a number of ways. In addition to using `Show` or `Inset` as suggested by Jens and Sjoerd, one can simply append the original data set as an additional series in the first argument of `ListPlot`: Let

```
 dta = Thread[{Range[25], Prime[Range[25]]}];
 trdta = {#} & /@ dta; (* or List/@dta *)
 trdta2 = Append[trdta, dta];
```

and use `trdta2` as the data input in `ListPlot` with option `Joined->True`.

```
 (* markers with colors and sizes tied to input data: *)
 markerlist = 
 Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Hue[#/50], Disk[], Opacity[1], Hue[#/100], 
 Text[Style[#, FontSize -> (10 + #/6)]]}, 
 ImageSize -> (15 + #/3)] & /@ dta[[All, 2]];
 ListPlot[trdta2, PlotMarkers -> Append[markerlist, ""], Frame -> True,
 Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 2}, {1, 5}}]
```

[image]

Still ... Jens's answer using `BubbleChart` is my favorite as `BubbleChart` provides many more convenient wrappers and options.

Comment: Hi KGLR, it's me again.  This first plot above looks perfect for me. However, I've a two dimension data set ,{{1.704, 0.931508}, {3.6, 2.7256}, {4.568, 3.89257}, {6.016, 
  5.77674}, {5.92, 7.05187}, {6.0904, 7.05187}, {6.72, 
  6.23791}, {7.52, 6.23791}, {6.96, 7.16941}, {6.96, 7.16941}, {7.12, 
  7.16941}, {6.56, 7.16941}, {6.72, 7.16941}}.          This list represents x-axis versus y-axis.  Please can you adapt your solution above to plot this data? Thanks

Comment: I've just raised this as a separate question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140713/label-markers-on-listplot-but-for-two-dimensional-data

Answer (score 8):

Both Chris and kguler's solution work by letting `ListPlot` think it is plotting 25 data sets of 1 point each. `ListPlot` lets you define a plot marker for every dataset separately.

That is all great and fine as long as you don't want to connect the points using the option `Joined->True`. Since all points are the single member of a dataset no line will be drawn.

By manipulating the output of the original plot it can still be done. `ListPlot` generates a `GraphicsComplex` in which every data point is represented by a single number. This number is used to position the `Inset`-s that are used to show the plot markers.

So, here is the original plot with `Joined` option added and assigned to a variable:

```
td = Prime[Range[25]];
dsk = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];
pl = ListPlot[td, PlotMarkers -> {dsk, 0.03}, Joined -> True];
```

Extracting the coordinates:

```
pts = Cases[pl, GraphicsComplex[coords_List, _] :> coords]
```

Replacing the plot markers with something else dependent on the coordinates:

```
pl /. Inset[_, pos_, rest___] :> 
      Inset[Graphics[{Circle[], Text[pts[[1, pos, 2]], {0.4, 0}]}], pos, rest]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
td = List /@ Transpose[{Range[25], Prime[Range[25]]}];
fcn = Graphics[
     {ColorData[1, #], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10] & /@ Range[25];
ListPlot[td, PlotMarkers -> fcn, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Somewhat similar to kguler's answer, but I'll leave it for now.