# Plot markers for monthly data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following data

```
    hours={38.9, 39, 38.9, 39, 39.3, 39.7, 39.2, 38.8, 39.6, 39.8, 39.9, 40.3, \
40, 40.2, 40.8, 40.7, 40.8, 41.2, 40.6, 40.7, 40.7, 40.9, 40.6, 40.8, \
40.3, 40.4, 40.7, 40.5, 40.7, 41.2, 40.3, 39.7, 40.4, 40.1, 40.3, \
40.6, 40.1, 40.5, 40.8, 40.8, 40.9, 41.7}
```

The first entry belongs to January of year 1, the second to February of year 1, and so on.

If I plot this with `ListPlot[hours, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
   "11", "12"}]`

[image]
I don't get the desired result, which is to have the right number corresponding to the right month...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible dup http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7408/2079

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the different elements of your `PlotMarkers` option refer to different data sets, whereas you just have the one data set.

If you were only after different coloured data points then you could `Style` each element of your data set, however I don't know if its possible to do this with different symbols.

A kind of hacky solution is just to convert your data set into many set each with one data point, as follows:

```
    ListPlot[List /@ Transpose[{Range[Length[hours]], hours}], 
        PlotMarkers -> ToString /@ Range[Length[hours]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question I gather you simply want the markers 1-12 repeated, in which case use something like:

```
    PlotMarkers->PadRight[{}, Length[hours],
        Table[Style[ToString[i], ColorData["Rainbow"][(i - 1)/11]], {i, 12}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Quantum

Comment: What should I do if I wanted to begin at number 6, and still maintain the same period of 12?

Comment: Many ways to get there, using `Mod` seems sensible to me, change `ToString[i]` to `ToString[Mod[i + 4, 12] + 1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to say the exact same thing. I've just managed to do it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPlot[MapThread[
  Labeled[#1, Style[#2, Bold, 12]] &, {hours, 
   PadRight[Range[12], Length[hours], "Periodic"]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Algohi