# Label Markers On ListPlot, but for Two Dimensional Data

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I found this answer below however I have a 2D data set.

[ListPlot with plotmarkers determined by point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/listplot-with-plotmarkers-determined-by-point)

The first plot answer by KGLR (answered Jun 24 '12 at 14:40) looks suitable. However, I've a two dimension data set

```
data = {{1.704, 0.931508}, {3.6, 2.7256}, {4.568, 3.89257}, {6.016, 5.77674}, {5.92, 7.05187}, {6.0904, 7.05187}, {6.72, 6.23791}, {7.52, 6.23791}, {6.96, 7.16941}, {6.96, 7.16941}, {7.12, 7.16941}, {6.56, 7.16941}, {6.72, 7.16941}}
```

This list represents x-axis versus y-axis. I require to adapt the solution  to plot the data. I would prefer a different colour scheme to HUE, and also add legend, with x and y axis labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the clutter you can modify the linked answer as follows:

```
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data]]; 
labels = Range@Length@data;
legendlabels = "Case " <> ToString@# & /@ labels;

ListPlot[List /@ data, Frame -> True,  ImageSize -> 700,
 PlotMarkers -> (Style[Framed[#], "Panel", #2, Background -> Opacity[.1, #2]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{labels, colors}]), 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[legendlabels, LegendLayout -> Grid], 
 FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: .. perhaps new-in -version-10 `Callout` may be more useful for displaying your data.

Comment: Perhaps to reduce the clutter, you could you define a different shape marker for each point? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi KGLR, Thanks for you efforts. My graph comes out different to yours, with the numbered boxes far larger and overlapping. How do I rescale? Also on the legend, how do I switch to list string "Case 1", "Case 2", "Case 3"......etc instead of the numerical values of the point.

Comment: @SPIL, thank you for the accept. Please see the update regarding legend labels.